# How to use SQLAlchemy HSTORE in Pyramid?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid, hstore

I have a model using the new PostgreSQL HSTORE support added to SQLAlchemy 0.8:

```
class Gateway(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'gateway'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    access = Column(Mutable.as_mutable(HSTORE), nullable=False, unique=True)
```

But when I run `session.query(Gateway).all()`, the following exception is raised:

```
ValueError: Attribute 'access' does not accept objects of type <type 'dict'>
```

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What sqlalchemy version is this? 0.7, 0.8?

Comment: You should really include a full traceback instead of just the exception itself.

Comment: Have you seen https://gist.github.com/dahlia/1859653 ?

Comment: And how about: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/changelog/migration_08.html#postgresql-hstore-type ? Does it work if you do it like in the example?

Comment: @codeape: This is almost exactly like in the example in the [HSTORE documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.HSTORE).

Comment: @codeape: And `MutableType` has been replaced by the `Mutable` extension, as used by the OP here; the gist you link to is outdated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SQLAlchemy example](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.HSTORE) shows the `Column` using a `MutableDict` whereas you are using `Mutable`. This discrepancy lines up pretty well with the error message you are seeing.